# I'm having a problem setting fonts for static text

Tags: c++, mfc

My problem is that the font in the text won't show up as the font that I want it to be. I looked up the issue but I didn't see any solutions. The text is the "Sign In"

```
BOOL Account::OnInitDialog() {
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    CFont font;
    VERIFY(font.CreatePointFont(160, _T("Arial")));
    SignInStatic.SetFont(&font);
    font.DeleteObject();

    return TRUE;
}
```

[image: The Sign In Text]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Win32 to use Windows XP style fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029573/how-to-get-win32-to-use-windows-xp-style-fonts)

Comment: Your function works, but you are immediately destroying the font with `font.DeleteObject()`. Declare `CFont font;` as a member of `Account` dialog class and don't call `font.DeleteObject()`. That way the font will be destroyed when the instance of `Account` dialog is destroyed.

Comment: Thx you solved it. Any reason why I had to change  font.SetFont(&font) to GetDlgItem(SignInText)->SetFont(&font);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `CWnd::SetFont()`, the window you assigned the font to does not take ownership of the font. You are responsible to delete the font, but only **when it is no longer in use**.

As often, the documentation of the underlying Windows API, which is [`WM_SETFONT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-setfont), provides more information than the MFC documentation:

> The application should call the DeleteObject function to delete the
>   font when it is no longer needed; for example, after it destroys the
>   control.

As you are using the `CFont` class, you don't have to explicitly call `DeleteObject()`. `CFont` is a [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) class that automatically destroys its associated resource in its destructor.

All you have to care about is the **scope** of the `CFont` instance. Currently you create a local variable of `CFont` in the `OnInitDialog` method. Even when you remove the explicit `DeleteObject` call, the font will be destroyed when `OnInitDialog` returns and the window you assigned the font to now refers to an **invalid font handle**.

## Solution

Declare an instance of `CFont` as a member variable of the `Account` class:

```
class Account : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    // Some stuff
private:
    CFont m_signInFont;
};
```

In `OnInitDialog` you have to use the member variable instead of the local variable and remove the `DeleteObject` call:

```
BOOL Account::OnInitDialog() {
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    VERIFY(m_signInFont.CreatePointFont(160, _T("Arial")));
    SignInStatic.SetFont(&m_signInFont);

    return TRUE; 
}
```

Now the font object will exist for the whole livetime of the dialog, which includes its children. You could even assign it to other children, as needed.